# Blurry painter effect using BitmapData

Tags: flash, actionscript, effects, particles

Looking to produce some effects using particles bleeding into one another and slowly fading away, but I wanted to get a good perspective on doing it using BitmapData.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at PixelBender

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/pixelbenderplugin/

Start by reading up on here here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/pixel_bender_basics.html

Comment: This may also be something you're looking for: Particle Editor for Starling Framework - blog.onebyonedesign.com/flash/particle-editor-for-starling-framework/